# Proving by induction that $n! < (\frac{n+1}{2})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction, factorial

As an analysis homework I have to prove by induction that

$n! < (\frac{n+1}{2})^n : (2 \le n \in\mathbb{N})$

For $n = 2$ this is trivial, but for $n+1$ no matter how I transform the equation I can't seem to get $(\frac{n+2}{2})^{n+1}$ on the right-hand side. I'm sure that this is an easy homework and I'm missing something blatantly obvious but the closest I got was $(n+1)! < \frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{2^{n}}$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By hypothesis, we have

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)!&=(n+1)n!\\\\
&<(n+1)\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n\\\\
&=2\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\end{align}$$

From Bernoulli's Inequality, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^{n+1} &=\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\\\
&\ge 2\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n+1} 
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: @ClementC. sure. Notice, however, that with four people posting answers of some sort, one thing is not happening: the person who asked participating in any way.

Comment: Would it be possible to start with the $n+1$ case on the LHS and show it must be greater than the RHS?

Comment: @willjagy Just curious as to your reason for commenting here to CC?

Comment: @zz20s This is equivalent.  Just reverse the order of logic.

Comment: Oh, i had a comment saying roughly: "damn, now that you have edited your answer to add more details, the reference to your answer from mine, saying 'if you are looking for a hint only, check Dr.MV's answer,' becomes irrelevant."

Comment: The additional detail is that Clement's original comment was still in place during the brief time it took to type my comment, and was above my comment. It only disappeared when I clicked on "Add Comment," meaning it was most likely deleted during those preceding 60 seconds.

Comment: @willjagy No worry.  I was curious as to its meaning without my having seen CC's preceding comment.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{ \left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)^n}{\left( \frac{n}{2} \right)^{n-1}} \; \; = \; \; \frac{1}{2} \; n \; \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n $$

Answer (score 1):

**A full derivation.** *Stop here if you only are looking for a hint.*

Assume $$
n! < \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n
$$
holds for some $n\geq 2$. Then,
$$
(n+1)! = (n+1)n! < (n+1)\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n
$$
by the induction hypothesis. Now, it remains to conclude to show that
$$
(n+1)\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n \leq \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^{n+1}
$$
that is, rearranging, that
$$
\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2}.
$$
But the LHS is 
$$
\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1} = \left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}
= e^{(n+1)\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)}
\leq 
e^{-\frac{n+1}{n+2}} \leq e^{-\frac{3}{4}} < \frac{1}{2}
$$
using first that $\ln(1+x) \leq x$, and then the monotonicity of $\exp$ (and the fact that $n\geq 2$).

Comment: The last inequality follows from the "fact" that [$e^{-3/4} \simeq 0.47$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=E%5E(-3%2F4)) ("of course").

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that some induction proofs are more cleanly presented if you use $n-1$ for the inductive hypothesis.  That is, let's assume we have $(n-1)!\lt\left(n\over2\right)^{n-1}$.  Then

$$n!=n(n-1)!\lt n\left(n\over2\right)^{n-1}=2\left(n\over2\right)^n$$

and hence it suffices to show that

$$2\le\left(n+1\over n\right)^n=\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n$$

This is perhaps easiest to show with a separate induction argument to establish that $(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$ for any $x$.  In this case, using $n$ for the induction hypothesis works cleanly:  If $(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$, then

$$(1+x)^{n+1}=(1+x)(1+x)^n\ge(1+x)(1+nx)=1+(n+1)x+nx^2\ge1+(n+1)x$$

Once you have $(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$ for any $x$, you can let $x={1\over n}$ and get

$$\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n\ge1+n\cdot{1\over n}=1+1=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Without induction
and completely elementary:

$n!
= \prod_{k=1}^n k
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
n!^2
&= (\prod_{k=1}^n k)^2\\
&= (\prod_{k=1}^n k)(\prod_{k=1}^n k)\\
&= (\prod_{k=1}^n k)(\prod_{k=1}^n (n+1-k))\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k)\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n (k(n+1)-k^2)\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}-\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}+k(n+1)-k^2\right)\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}-\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}-k(n+1)+k^2\right)\right)\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}-\left(\dfrac{n+1}{2}-k\right)^2\right)\\
&> \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}\right)\\
&= \left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}\right)^n\\
&= \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)^{2n}\\
\text{so}\\
n!
&> \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n}\\
\end{array}
$